# Module error with ngRoute in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, json, ngroute

I'm trying to setup a feature for an app that will display the content of a given id from JSON based on the `id` parameter in the URL. I'm getting the error in console `Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.` The URL should be `url-to-site/app/{id#}`, and by entering the id# of the object in JSON, the view should change to correspond to that details of that id.

I currently have this as my setup:

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
        controller: 'appController'
    });
})

.controller('appController', function($routeParams,$scope, $http) {
  console.log($routeParams.id);
  $scope.indexToShow = 0;
    $http.get("shows.json")
      .then(function(response) {
        // console.log(response);
        $scope.results = response.data;
      });
      $scope.changeNext = function(){
        $scope.indexToShow = ($scope.indexToShow + 1) % $scope.results.length;
      };
      $scope.changePrevious = function(){
        if($scope.indexToShow != 0){
           $scope.indexToShow = ($scope.indexToShow - 1) % $scope.results.length;
        }
      };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="appController">
  ...template code
 </div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "count": 54,
    "image_location": "images/image-name.jpg"
  }
]
```

Comment: add `ng-view` directive  in your html to load the routing templates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all, but maybe the problem it's because you forgot the ',' in the config of the route.

```
 $routeProvider.when('/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'index.html' ,// <-- HERE
    controller: 'appController'
});
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but I still can't access the data by id with `url-to-site/app/id#`

Comment: I've tried `$routeProvider.when('/:id', {});`, but it has no affect.

Comment: I mean if you try to use the url     url-to-site/#id without the "app"